# Protractor: Is it possible to reload/refresh frame in protractor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

Does protractor allows refreshing a single frame instead of using `browser.refresh()` to refresh the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame has a `Window` object associated with it that is the window which holds the contents of the frame. It is conveniently located in a field named `.contentWindow`. This window has a `location` field, which has a `reload()` method. So, supposing your frame has `"frame"` for id:

```
browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.location.reload();");
```

Or if you have already a reference to your frame on the JavaScript side and it is in the `frame` variable:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].contentWindow.location.reload();", frame.getWebElement());
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to reset the `src` attribute of a frame ([source](http://qainsight.blogspot.com/2013/02/refresh-iframe-using-webdriver.html)), not tested:

```
var frame = element(by.id("myFrame"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].src = arguments[0].src", frame.getWebElement());
```